# Dynamically Select Some Options In Dropdown List In Angular Material 2 Version 6

Tags: angular-material2

I have a form for editing user profiles.  In it is a drop down list of skill checkboxes, multiple select.  I get the previously selected options / skills array [1, 3, 7] from the db in the profile data object and I want to show those skills as checked in the edit profile form.  When the user is editing their profile they can see what they previously selected.

myForm.html

```
  <li><label class="label-pad">Select main skills: </label>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select  placeholder="Select your skills" type="text" id="skillIds"
                   formControlName="skill_id_array" required multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let skill of skills"
                    [value]="skill.skill_id">{{skill.skill_name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </li>
```

As the data is delivered by the observable I have this for capturing the array of skill_id's that are in the db:

```
this.skill_ids = data.skill_id_array; // [1, 3, 7]
```

After the dropdown is instantiated I need to loop through this.skill_ids and somehow check the relevant boxes in the dropdown. Maybe this is a start but I'm lost at this point.  Any ideas?

```
//  Check the previously selected option boxes in the skills dropdown list.

private checkSelectedOptions(skill_ids) {
  console.log('skill array', skill_ids);  // [1, 3, 7]

  // Need to loop through the array and match id's with names and check the proper checkboxes.

  for (let i = 0; i < skill_ids.length; i++) {
  console.log('skill_ids: ', skill_ids[i]); 
  }
}
```

Comment: this might help: https://netbasal.com/handling-multiple-checkboxes-in-angular-forms-57eb8e846d21

Comment: @MA-Maddin Thank you but that example is for user initiated actions.  I need the code to do this based on previous user actions, checking the select boxes.  I stumbled into the answer and will post that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm no hero, I stumbled into the solution after writing too much code.  The data.skill_id_array line will display the previously checked selected options in the dropdown list when it loads into the edit form.  A very simple solution compared to where I was originally going with this.

```
this.httpService.getRecordById(this.dbTable, this.recordId)
            .subscribe(data => {
                data.skill_id_array = data.skill_id_array.map(Number); // Displays previously checked boxes in edit view.
                this.fillForm(data);
```

My complete edit form for those who want to see the solution in context.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Inject, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { HttpService } from '../../services/http.service';
import { MemberModel } from '../member.model';
import { AddEditFormComponent } from '../add-edit-form/add-edit-form.component';
import { EditProcessorService } from '../../services/processors/edit-processor.service';
import { MessagesService } from '../../services/messages-service/messages.service';
import { FormErrorsService } from '../../services/form-validation/form-errors.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-member',
  templateUrl: './edit-member.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class EditMemberComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  private dbTable = 'members';
  private formValue: MemberModel;
  private skill_ids;

  private recordId: number;
  private dbColumn;
  private paginator;
  private dataSource;

  private subscription: Subscription; // For ngOnDestroy.

  // This is a form group from FormBuilder.
  @ViewChild(AddEditFormComponent) private addEditForm: AddEditFormComponent;



  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditMemberComponent>,  // Used in modal for close()
    private messagesService: MessagesService,
    public formErrorsService: FormErrorsService,
    private editProcessorService: EditProcessorService,
  ) {}



  // ---- GET DATA BY ID ----


// Need to load the data after the form is rendered so ngOnInit didn't work.
// setTimeout is a hack to avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.fetchRecord();
    }, 200);
  }

  public fetchRecord() {

    this.recordId = this.data.recordId;
    this.dbColumn = this.data.dbColumn;
    this.paginator = this.data.paginator;
    this.dataSource = this.data.dataSource;

    // Display the data retrieved from the data model to the form model.
    this.httpService.getRecordById(this.dbTable, this.recordId)
        .subscribe(data => {
            data.skill_id_array = data.skill_id_array.map(Number); // Displays previously checked boxes in edit view.
            this.fillForm(data);
          },
          (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(err.error);
            console.log(err.message);
            this.handleError(err);
          });
  }



  // Populate the form, called above in fetchRecord().

  private fillForm(parsedData) {
    this.addEditForm.addEditMemberForm.setValue({
      first_name: parsedData.first_name,
      middle_initial: parsedData.middle_initial,
      last_name: parsedData.last_name,
      skill_id_array: parsedData.skill_id_array,
      ...
    });
  }

// ---- UPDATE ----  Called from edit-member.component.html

  public update() {

    // right before we submit our form to the server we check if the form is valid
    // if not, we pass the form to the validateform function again. Now with check dirty false
    // this means we check every form field independent of whether it's touched.
    // https://hackernoon.com/validating-reactive-forms-with-default-and-custom-form-field-validators-in-angular-5586dc51c4ae.

    if (this.addEditForm.addEditMemberForm.valid) {

      this.formValue = this.addEditForm.addEditMemberForm.value;

      this.httpService.updateRecord(this.dbTable, this.recordId, this.formValue)
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            // Update the table data view for the changes.
            this.editProcessorService.updateDataTable(result, this.recordId, this.dbColumn, this.paginator, this.dataSource);
            this.success();
          },
          (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(err.error);
            console.log(err.message);
            this.handleError(err);
          }
        );
    } else {
      this.addEditForm.formErrors = this.formErrorsService.validateForm(
        this.addEditForm.addEditMemberForm,
        this.addEditForm.formErrors, false
      );
    }
    this.reset();

  }



  // ---- UTILITIES ----


  private reset() {
    this.addEditForm.addEditMemberForm.reset();
  }

  private success() {
    this.messagesService.openDialog('Success', 'Database updated as you wished!');
  }

  private handleError(error) {
    this.messagesService.openDialog('Error em1', 'Please check your Internet connection.');
  }
}
```

Comment: I read your code like that: let's say user Tom checks 3 out of 5 skill checkboxes and saves the data. Later he returns and wants to edit the skills. Now he only sees the chosen 3 skills as options. (because you give the stored data which is saved skills into the mat-options) Is that right? Or did I read something  wrong? If I'm right, it wouldn't make much sense, because Tom only could choose less than before...

Comment: Nope, all options remain in the drop down.  That is because when the edit form loads it populates the drop down from the db with the latest skills, including new additions, and then the user data is loaded.  The user's skill array checks those 3 boxes so Tom can see what he selected but he can change those.  By the way, I just dumped REST for GraphQL and I had to do a lot of refactoring but the form works the same.